# How to calculate an index $(G:U)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I have the group $G = \def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z/9\Z$ and the subgroup $U = \{\bar 0,\bar 3,\bar 6\} \subseteq  G$.

My first question is, what mean the lines over the elements of the subgroup.
And how can I calculate $U|G$ or $(G:U)$.

Thank you very very much.

Comment: First, you look up the definition of $(G:U)$.

Comment: i looked it up. its #u|G and u|G := {aU | a element G}

Comment: OK, so then you calculate $aU$ for various elements $a$ of $G$ and see how many different answers you get, and there's your $(G:U)$.

Comment: Ah, but the group operation is *addition*, not multiplication.

Comment: aaah ok, so its 0U, 1U, 2U ? so the index is 3 ?

Comment: And what does the lines mean, over 0,3 and 6?

Comment: They indicate that you're dealing with cosets. So in your case, $\bar{0}=0+9\mathbb{Z} = \{0+9z:z\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: so the zero isnt just a number in Z, its a whole coset?

Comment: Indeed so, @user36371

Comment: so my answer was nevertheless right? The solution is 3, and u|G = {0U,1U,2U}?

Comment: Yes, but, since the operation is addition, it's probably better to write $\{\,0+U,1+U,2+U\,\}$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much guys. =)

Comment: @user36371 Feel free to write an answer to your question, so that the question is marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines above the numbers indicate that they are cosets.

To calculate $u|G$ you have to calculate $x|G$ for all elements $x\in(U)$ and see how much different solutions you get.

In this case $u|G$ = {$0+U, 1+U, 2+U$}.
To calculate the index $(G:U)$ its #$u|G$.

So the index is 3.